# How to show that $N(A) = R{(A^*)}^\perp$  and $N(A^*)=R({A})^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to show that for a given square matrices $N(A) = R{(A^*)}^\perp$ and $N(A^*)=R{(A)}^\perp$ where $N(A) $ and $R(A) $ are the null and range spaces of matrix $A$, respectively?

I am not able to figure out how to start?I find difficulty when I have to deal with the orthogonal complement of subspaces.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: The second statement must be $N(A^*) = R(A)^{\perp}$.

Comment: @Marvis Thanks for pointing please edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT** Let $z \in N(A)$ and $x \in R(A^*)$. This gives us $Az = 0$ and $x = A^*b$, for some $b$. $x^*z = b^*Az = 0$. Hence, $x \perp z$.

Comment: I need hint for second part too. Can you please help me out?

Comment: @srijan Replace $A$ by $A^*$ and make use of the fact that $(A^*)^* = A$

Comment: Let $z\in N(A)^*$ and $x\in R(A)$. This gives us $A^*z = 0$ and $x = Ab$, for some $b$. Further $x^*z = b^*A^*z = 0$. Hence, $x \perp z$. Am I correct?

Comment: @srijan yes....

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me.